# TSP function with pgrouting

Tags: qgis, postgis, pgrouting, routing, osm2pgrouting

I'm trying the TSP function with pgrouting with just a few of the many nodes obtained with osm2pgrouting (I also have the edges, of course).
I'm not an expert but once I run the query, it works and gives me a seemingly correct result. The point is that I actually want to check this query with DB manager on QGIS but I don't know how to do it: If I don't add the geometries, I get stuck here.
If I didn't get it wrong, I have to join the_geom column to the code I just wrote.

Could someone tell me what I need to write in order to see my work on QGIS?

This is what I wrote and I have to finish including the geometries:

```
select * from pgr_TSP(
    $$
    SELECT * FROM pgr_dijkstraCostMatrix(
    'SELECT gid as id, source, target, cost, reverse_cost FROM
    public.ways',
    (select array_agg(id) from public.ways_vertices_pgr where id in
    (729,203,314,579,621,85852,719)), directed := false)
    $$,
    start_id := 729,
    
    randomize := false
        );
```